# from two tensors how to create generator over raws

Tags: tensorflow, generator, tensor

Suppose I have two tensors X_train (inputs) and Y_train ( for targets) where in every raw there is a sample.
From those two tensors, I want to create a data generator in order to use in the model.fit(). Because i want to use workers.

the fit method should be as follow

```
model.fit(generator(X_train, y_train),
          workers =os.cpu_count(), 
          max_queue_size=10,)
```

Comment: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly?